# Microsoft Graph Api in .net Core 2.0? Managing AD users via Web App

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I'd like to add/edit/remove user contents via a .Net Core 2.0 Web App. I already created a tenant and custom policies and the Web App is working fine. I need to find a way to get and edit the contents of the tenant, add/edit/remove users, reset passwords etc. via the App. I figured Graph Api is probably the only way to do that. The thing is, my app is in .Net Core 2.0 and there's no way of migrating. Are there any other ways of implementing the funcionality I need, or is there any way to use Graph Api in .Net Core 2.0?

I am using this code sample : [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/tree/aspnet_core_2_0)

```
 Response from Graph:

{
"error": {
"code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
"message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
"innerError": {
"request-id": "xxx",
"date": "xxx"
}
}
}
```

[Image of Perms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTTXy.png)

/// Thank you so much juunas you're amazing.

Comment: You should be able to just ADAL/MSAL to get the access token and then call the Graph API with HttpClient. But I do think there was even a library for interacting with the Graph API. Just saying you can send the requests manually too if needed.

Comment: Having done an app like this with "classic" MVC, one word of caution :). If you want your app by itself to be able to reset passwords, it has to have pretty much an admin role on the service principal. At that time there was no permission you can give that allows resets.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Do you happen to have any code snippets showing how the token is acquired and the Graph API is called?

Comment: Okay nevermind, I think I found what I needed, and it seems that the app is yours :) I'm speaking of [this one](https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore2aadauth). I configured the app but I have a problem with it. After Signing in and launching MS Graph test, I get an error I linked in the edited thread. Any clue why this happens? The user I'm using has full permissions in AD.

Comment: That means you haven't granted the necessary permissions to the app. You need to add and grant the permissions in Azure portal.

Comment: Here is also the blog article I wrote accompanying that sample: https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-2-azure-ad-authentication

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you :). I just need to figure out how to add the permissions to my web app now.

Comment: Hm, it seems that I'm stuck. I am using an admin account to login, I also gave the B2C app full permissions in App Registrations. What am I missing?

Comment: Check the access token for example at https://jwt.io. Check if the roles/scopes are there.

Comment: Um, where can I get the token?

Comment: You can debug the app and use a breakpoint to stop its execution to when you first get the access token for the Graph API. E.g. here: https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore2aadauth/blob/master/Core2AadAuth/Startup.cs#L69

Comment: Alright, I'm not sure why but it seems they aren't. [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ss5f0Kzm).

Comment: Could you add a screenshot to your question of the permissions you have given?

Comment: Just to be sure I added literally all of them. Added pic to question. Although I am not sure if I have done this correctly.

Comment: You have to add permissions to Microsoft Graph API :) You have added permissions only for Azure AD Graph API. Two different APIs.

Comment: I just connected everything to Microsoft Graph API (except the Authority link) and I got a response from MS Graph test. A long string with all  the contents from User Claims, just mine though. Now I need to find a way of modying the http graph query to get all the users instead of just me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a discussion in the comments, the problem turned out to be giving permissions to Azure AD Graph API instead of Microsoft Graph API.

And if you want all the users, use this request URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

More info about the users endpoint in MS Graph: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/users

Comment: Alright, but how can I add or edit a user? The request is the same. https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users for both cases.                                                             /// nevermind! You just edit HttpMethod.Get to HttpMethod.XXX (the one at the beginning of the call). :)

Comment: Yeah! You can find guidance for the different actions here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user

Comment: Alright, one last question. Is there maybe a way of getting the queried contents in a nicer form than a large string with a lot of unnecessary (for display) data, or do you just have to edit the string? I'm referencing to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46243449/modifying-ms-graph-responses-for-display-on-site) thread of mine.

Comment: You should make a class modeling the fields you are interested in the returned data structure, and then use something like JSON.NET to deserialize it. Or you can just use the Microsoft Graph API client library: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph

Comment: Oh, about the PUT call. You just insert a serialized json with all the properties stored in it to the end of the call, or do you pass it differently? I'm not quite sure where to put it.