# Modifying MS Graph responses for display on site

Tags: string, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a c# Web App that connects to Azure AD B2C directory with MS Graph to display user data. I'm looking for a best practice way to display the contents returned by Graph Query. I could always do straight forward string formatting, but I'm looking for something more optimal.

I use

```
HttpResponseMessage httpmsg = await QueryGraphAsync("/users?$select=displayName");
```

and the response looks like this :

> {"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users(displayName)","value":[{"displayName":"xxx@xxx.xxx Xxx"}]}

There is just one user at this momment. What I'd like to get is "xxx@xxx.xxx Xxx" without playing around with string modification that would resolve around finding displayName, skipping a few chars and reading up untill it finds a quotation mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Microsoft Graph is a REST API which returns JSON. Rather than doing "string modification" you should treat the response as a JSON object, which can easily be converted into an array or dictionary.

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users(displayName)","value":[{"displayName":"xxx@xxx.xxx Xxx"}]}')

var str = JSON.stringify(obj.value[0].displayName)

document.write(str)
```

This is how you should treat all of the responses you get from the Microsoft Graph. Let me know if this helps!